# Closed vote remains after comment was deleted

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I "pulled the trigger" on a question that was an 'exact duplicate' however, I realized that I had NOT copied the **correct** duplicate to show the example.

The incorrect example was now shown in the comment box at the bottom of the question. OOPS! So, now to correct this fu-pa I can delete my own comment....DONE!

Not so easy. The closed vote remained.

Can I reconcile the closed vote or is it up to the community to over-ride this mistake. Should it be reported as a mistake and/or flagged for a review?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no retracting a close vote.

However, it will expire in its own time (48 hours? can't remember exactly). If you think your vote will wrongly encourage people to vote against something, leave a comment explaining why you think it should stay open (eg, why it isn't a dupe).

But either way, people shouldn't be blindly voting to close things. If a miscarriage of justice does happen, it only takes one flag for a moderator to re-open something.

Comment: 48-72. The number keeps changing, or rather, it is difficult to calculate. ;)

Comment: I think it's a long longer than that. Willing to say it's a couple days at least.